# Rudin Theorem 3.25 - Convergent Series - Real or Complex?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Starting out the section SERIES of chapter 3 in Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin says "In the remainder of this chapter, all sequences and series under consideration wil be complex-valued, unless the contrary is explicitly stated."

Theorem 3.25 (a) reads "If $|a_n| \leq c_n$ for $n \geq N_0$, where $N_0$ is some fixed integer, and if $\sum c_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges.

I think that $\{c_n\}$ is a real sequence unless I am missing something (maybe the author thinks it's 'explicitly stated' by using an order). Is that right?

(if it wouldn't be real, we could probably just define a real sequence $\{c'_n\}$ to be $\{|c_n|\}$) and the theorem would hold with $\{c'_n\}$).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $\le$ is defined for real numbers only, not on the rest of $\mathbb C$. Therefore, the quantities that appear on both sides of $\le $ must be real.